# Image slide with Javascript

Tags: javascript

> i have an image slide here with prototyping . Something is wrong and i cant fix it . I understand that in setInterval the context is lost , and i try to bind it , but it doesnt work . Also tried to wrap , but it didnt work too. what can i do whit this problem ?

```js
function Slide() {
  this.currentStep = 0;
  this.time = 2000;
  this.images = [];

  this.images[0] = 'images/image1.jpg';
  this.images[1] = 'images/image2.jpg';
  this.images[2] = 'images/image3.jpg';
  this.images[3] = 'images/image4.jpg';
  this.images[4] = 'images/image5.jpg';

}

Slide.prototype.carousel = function() {
  document.querySelector('.image').src = this.images[this.currentStep];

  this.currentStep < this.images.length - 1 ? this.currentStep += 1 : this.currentStep = 0;

  setInterval(carousel.bind(Slide), this.time);
}

const imageSlide = new Slide();
imageSlide.carousel();
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <img class="image" width="1000" height="500" alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: I added in the snippet ...now you can see

Comment: Is there an element with class image? Because you use  `document.querySelector('.image')`

Comment: yes , it's an image

Comment: No, I asked if  you have an element , `div`, `image` etc with a `class` name `image`, cause I think you think that you can access the image element with `.image` which you can not unless it's the name of it's class.

Comment: Please remember that you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the given answers if your request has been resolved @NorayrGhukasyan.

Answer (score 1):

There are three problems with your code:

1. The function `carousel` doesn't exist. Perhaps you mean `Slide.prototype.carousel` or, if used inside the function, `this.carousel`.
2. Also, instead of binding the constructor `Slide`, you should bind the instance `this`.
3. Finally, since you are passing `this.carousel` into `setInterval`, the function will be executed recursively in an asynchronous manner. However, not as expected, since with every execution you'll be creating more and more intervals repeating the above. Use `setTimeout` instead.

**Snippet:**

```js
function Slide() {
  this.currentStep = 0;
  this.time = 2000;
  this.images = [
    'images/image1.jpg',
    'images/image2.jpg',
    'images/image3.jpg',
    'images/image4.jpg',
    'images/image5.jpg'
  ];
}

Slide.prototype.carousel = function() {
  document.querySelector('.image').src = this.images[this.currentStep];

  this.currentStep < this.images.length - 1
    ? this.currentStep += 1
    : this.currentStep = 0;

  setTimeout(this.carousel.bind(this), this.time);
}

const imageSlide = new Slide();
imageSlide.carousel();
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <img class="image" width="1000" height="500" alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: This is better than the other answer which uses `setInterval(this.carousel.bind(imageSlide), this.time);` as that will cause all instances of Slide to bind carousel to the instance imageSlide

Comment: As I mentioned on the other answer, you will need a setTimeout rather than setInterval otherwise you end up with a steadily growing number of loops.

Comment: Correct @DBS. I didn't notice that at first. Since the function itself is passed as a callback, `setTimeout` should be used.

Comment: Your observation is astute @DhruvMurarka. However, it's not a matter of which answer is better or worse because the other answer you refer to doesn't work at all. If instead of `imageSlide`, a created instance is called something else the other answer will throw a `ReferenceError` in strict mode or otherwise bind `undefined` and throw a `TypeError` when `this.images` is run.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a slider function to Element.prototype then init using `element.slider(sliderInterval)`.

```js
Element.prototype.slider = function(slideInterval) {
  let currentStep = 1;
  let data = ['https://i.imgur.com/mcr23np.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/Eql027R.jpg', 'https://i.imgur.com/oUizZe6.jpg'];
  let imageElement = this.getElementsByClassName('image')[0];
  imageElement.src = data[0];

  setInterval(() => {
    imageElement.src = data[currentStep % data.length];
    currentStep++;
  }, slideInterval);
}

const mySlider = document.getElementById('mySlider');
mySlider.slider(4000);
```

```html
<div id="mySlider">
  <img class="image" alt="Falied To Load" />
</div>
```